# Show that $\text{Li}(x)=\int\limits_1^x\Big(1-\frac{1}{u}\Big)\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\log u}+ \log\log x+ C$

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

I wnat to show that
$$\text{Li}(x)=\int\limits_1^x\Big(1-\frac{1}{u}\Big)\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\log u}+ \log\log x+ C$$
with some constant $C$ and Li$(x)$ being the integral logarithm
$$\text{Li}(x)=\int\limits_0^x\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\log u}=\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to0} \Bigg(\int\limits_0^{1-\epsilon}\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\log t} + \int\limits_{1+\epsilon}^x \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\log t}\Bigg)$$

In this notation it seems like the second summand can remain. It is also clear that I get the summand $\log\log x$ from some term of the form
$$\int\limits_?^x\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{u\log u}$$
However, I strongly struggle to convert the summand $\int\limits_0^{1-\epsilon}\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\log t}$ in a form I need on the right side.

I would appreciate any hints on how to proof the aboves equality.

Comment: The function $\operatorname{Li}$ is defined so that it has the property $\operatorname{Li}'(x) = \frac{1}{\log x}$.  
Compute
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left[\int\limits_1^x\Big(1-\frac{1}{u}\Big)\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\log u}+ \log\log x\right] = \frac{1}{\log x}
$$
So
$$
\text{Li}(x)=\int\limits_1^x\Big(1-\frac{1}{u}\Big)\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\log u}+ \log\log x+ C
$$
holds on $(0,1)$ and on $(1,\infty)$, possibly with different constants for the two intervals.  So, is the question to determine whether the two constants are the same?

Comment: Maple computes these numerically, and finds the real parts of $\text{Li}(x)$ and $\int_1^x\Big(1-\frac{1}{u}\Big)\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\log u}+ \log\log x$ differ by $0.577$ on both $(0,1)$ and $(1,\infty)$.  But the imaginary parts differ by $3.14$ on $(0,1)$ and by $0$ on $(1,\infty)$.  Perhaps that $\pi i$ depends on the choice of branch of $\log \log x$ in $(0,1)$.

Comment: just to say that the first integral in this notation $\int\limits_0^x\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\log u}=\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to0} \Bigg(\int\limits_0^{1-\epsilon}\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\log t} + \int\limits_{1+\epsilon}^x \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\log t}\Bigg)$ is wrong, as the first integral have a clear meaning that is different from the RHS. The correct way to denote it is using directly the name of the function, that is, as $\operatorname{Li}(x)$, or with something like $\operatorname{P.V.}\int\limits_0^x\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\log u}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, separate the upper integral in the limit definition of $\operatorname{Li}$:
\begin{eqnarray}
\operatorname{Li}(x) &=& \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\left[\int_0^{1-\epsilon} + \int_{1+\epsilon}^x\right]\frac{du}{\ln u}\\ & = &\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\left[\int_0^{1-\epsilon}\frac{du}{\ln u}+
\int_{1+\epsilon}^x\left(1 - \frac{1}{u}\right)\frac{du}{\ln u} +
\int_{1+\epsilon}^x\frac{du}{u\ln u}\right]\\
&=& \int_1^x\left(1 - \frac{1}{u}\right)\frac{du}{\ln u} + \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\left[\int_0^{1-\epsilon}\frac{du}{\ln u} +
\int_{1+\epsilon}^e\frac{du}{u\ln u} + \int_e^x\frac{du}{u\ln u}\right]\\
 &=& \int_1^x\left(1 - \frac{1}{u}\right)\frac{du}{\ln u} + \log\log x + \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\left[\int_0^{1-\epsilon}\frac{du}{\ln u} +
\int_{1+\epsilon}^e\frac{du}{u\ln u}\right].
\end{eqnarray}
The term in brackets doesn't depend on $x$, so all we need to do is show that limit exists. Use a change of variables to get
\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\left[\int_0^{1-\epsilon}\frac{du}{\ln u} +
\int_{1+\epsilon}^e\frac{du}{u\ln u}\right] &=&
\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\left[\int_0^{1-\epsilon}\frac{du}{\ln u} +
\int_{\ln(1+\epsilon)}^{1}\frac{du}{u}\right] \\&=& \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\int_0^{1-\epsilon}\left[\frac{1}{\ln u} + \frac{1}{1-u}\right]du + \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\int_{\ln(1+\epsilon)}^\epsilon\frac{du}{u}
\\ & = & \int_0^1\left[\frac{1}{\ln u} + \frac{1}{1-u}\right]du.
\end{eqnarray}
The first limit is defined because the integrand no longer has a singularity at $1$, and the second can be evaluated explicitly as $\ln[\epsilon / \ln(1+\epsilon)]$, which vanishes as $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$. Thus we have
$$
\operatorname{Li}(x) = \int_1^x\left(1 - \frac{1}{u}\right)\frac{du}{\ln u} + \log\log x + \int_0^1\left[\frac{1}{\ln u} + \frac{1}{1-u}\right]du,
$$
where the last integral is some constant. As it happens, that constant is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_constant#Integrals), but finding that is a different problem.